# require a module with webpack

Tags: javascript, build, require, commonjs, webpack

I use Webpack in order to build my javascript of my website.

Everything work perfectly but I would like to call require into a template (added dynamically).

I want to be able to require a module after the build. (require is not defined into the global context).

Is it possible ?

Thx

Answer (score 8):

An option which is available to you now is to create a [context](http://webpack.github.io/docs/context.html) which you expose globally on `window`. I've had success using the following snippet:

```
// Create a `require` function in the global scope so that scripts that have
// not been webpack'd yet can still access them.
window["require"] = function (module) {
    return require("./public_modules/" + module + ".js");
}
```

Basically what you're doing is exposing a folder to webpack and telling it to pack all the files in that folder in to a chunk. You can then type `var moduleName = require("module-name")` outside of a webpack'd script.

As long as the above snippet is inside a file which gets bundled and evaluated, you will have a function defined on `window` (coincidentally named "require" but you can call it anything) which will use webpack's require functionality.