# Debugging in devtools with Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

With require.js it was very easy to debug a module in Chrome's DevTools, by simply entering:

```
require('my-module').callThisFunction()
```

With Webpack this is not possible anymore, because it compiles the modules via CLI and does not export `require`.

`window.webpackJsonp` is globally exposed, so I thought I could just find the module ID and call it like this: `webpackJsonp([1],[])`, but unfortunately this returns `undefined`.

Are there any workarounds to still be able to debug like require.js?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I require() from the console using webpack?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29223071/how-do-i-require-from-the-console-using-webpack)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add code to module in bundle

```
require.ensure([], function() {
  window.require = function(smth) {
    return require('./' + smth);
  };
});
```

Now you can use 'require' from chrome console like require('app').doSmth()

Answer (score 1):

You can get something pretty close using [expose-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expose-loader). Ie. for React you could have `{ test: require.resolve("react"), loader: "expose?React" }` at your loader configuration. After that you can access `React` through console. The same idea applies for other libraries.

Comment: Yeah, but then I would need to do this for every module that I have (and it would create globals). This takes away the ease of testing that I had before with require.js.

Comment: That's definitely true! I've "solved" this problem by using hot loading. If I want to introspect something I just add a `console.log` somewhere. After that it triggers my build and updates the browser where I can see the answer I was after. Would that work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately no, because being able to freely test all modules in the console can really speed up debugging. Is there really no way to just do something like `getWebpackModule(moduleId)`?

Comment: As far as I understand, nope. Webpack just gives you a bundle. Fortunately Webpack's watcher works fast during development so that helps a bit. Btw, see http://blog.player.me/ditching-requirejs-webpack-reasons-lessons-learned/ . Some good info on moving from RequireJS to Webpack.