# Call webpack bundled function/class from console.log

Tags: javascript, module, console, export, webpack

Is it possible to access the exported modules(ES6->ES5 compiled) from web inspector console? They are bundled together using webpack

I am trying to call Session.setSessionInLocalStorage('test key', 'test object');

```js
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/  // The module cache
/******/  var installedModules = {};
/******/
/******/  // The require function
/******/  function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {
/******/
/******/   // Check if module is in cache
/******/   if(installedModules[moduleId])
/******/    return installedModules[moduleId].exports;
/******/
/******/   // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/   var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/    exports: {},
/******/    id: moduleId,
/******/    loaded: false
/******/   };
/******/
/******/   // Execute the module function
/******/   modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);
/******/
/******/   // Flag the module as loaded
/******/   module.loaded = true;
/******/
/******/   // Return the exports of the module
/******/   return module.exports;
/******/  }
/******/
/******/
/******/  // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/  __webpack_require__.m = modules;
/******/
/******/  // expose the module cache
/******/  __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;
/******/
/******/  // __webpack_public_path__
/******/  __webpack_require__.p = "";
/******/
/******/  // Load entry module and return exports
/******/  return __webpack_require__(0);
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ([
/* 0 */
/*!*********************!*\
  !*** ./app/main.js ***!
  \*********************/
/***/ function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

 'use strict';
 
 var _CoreUtils = __webpack_require__(/*! ./Core/utils/session/Core.utils.Session */ 4);
 
 var mySession = new _CoreUtils.Session();
 
 mySession.setSessionInLocalStorage('key', 'my object');

/***/ },
/* 1 */,
/* 2 */,
/* 3 */,
/* 4 */
/*!******************************************************!*\
  !*** ./app/Core/utils/session/Core.utils.Session.js ***!
  \******************************************************/
/***/ function(module, exports) {

 "use strict";
 
 Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
     value: true
 });
 
 var _createClass = function () { function defineProperties(target, props) { for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) { var descriptor = props[i]; descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false; descriptor.configurable = true; if ("value" in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true; Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor); } } return function (Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) { if (protoProps) defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps); if (staticProps) defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps); return Constructor; }; }();
 
 function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }
 
 var Session = function () {
     function Session(sessionId) {
         _classCallCheck(this, Session);
 
         this.sessionId = sessionId;
     }
 
     _createClass(Session, [{
         key: "getSessionFromLocalStorage",
         value: function getSessionFromLocalStorage(sessionKey) {
             return localStorage.getItem(sessionKey);
         }
     }, {
         key: "setSessionInLocalStorage",
         value: function setSessionInLocalStorage(sessionKey, sessionData) {
             localStorage.setItem(sessionKey, JSON.stringify(sessionData));
         }
     }]);
 
     return Session;
 }();
 
 exports.Session = Session;

/***/ }
/******/ ]);
//# sourceMappingURL=app.js.map
```

Answer (score 3):

1) Open your devtools, the "Sources" panel.

2) open the `webpack://` in the explorer tab, you'll see your original ES6 files thanks to sourcemaps.

You can setup break points, access variables ...

Comment: Ok yes I see it under webpack://. I know I can set break points etc... I want to execute the function from console? isn't there like a global window object/namespace for me to access my modules from console and call it? e.g execute this from console? `Session.setSessionInLocalStorage('test key', 'test object');`

Comment: Put a breakpoint somewhere this class + method is accessible, then execute the function. In your case, import Session somewhere if you don't already have then you'll be able to play with it in the console.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes.**

Add following code to some module in bundle:

```
require.ensure([], function () {
    window.require = function (module) {
        return require(module);
    };
});
```

Use require from console:

```
require("./app").doSomething();
```

---

**EDIT:**

In TypeScript we use:

```
(require as any).ensure([], () => {
    window["require"] = module => require(module);
});
```

I'm currently instantiating/getting my services this way:

```
var contactsService= (new (require("./app").default)).contactsService;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add special code to your app. You can follow these steps:

- Place a breakpoint where you use the service/class that you later wish to   debug
- In the console, save it on the window for example `window.myService = this.props.myService`
- Use the saved reference on the window